# UITableView inside a UIViewController subclass causing recursive call to viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why am I getting a recursive call to viewDidLoad when I add a subview to my UIViewController?
I am doing a addSubView in the viewDidLoad method as soon as I do that it recursively call viewDidLoad again

Comment: maybe you added the same view as the sub view by mistake?

Comment: Please post your code. We can't make any sense of what's going on otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I found the problem. I forgot to set the view.

ALl I had to do in the viewDidLoad was to add this line:

self.view = myTableView;

instead of [[self view] addSubview:myTableView];

Comment: That doesn't sound as the right way to use UIViewController, because the view should have been available before `viewDidLoad`. How did you build the controller? by xib?

Comment: I set the view in loadView. I dont use nib